# Visual Studio 2012 menu 'analyze code coverage' is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

There is this great tool in Visual Studio 2012 to show the test coverage of the source code. On the [official MSDN homepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx) it is shown under menu `Test -> Analyze Code Coverage`.

But in my `Test` menu this entry is missing and I could'nt figure out why. Can someone please explain? Am I missing an addon/plugin?

**Update:** Visual Studio 2012 Professional with Update 3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the MSDN page you linked:

> Requirements
>
> ```
> Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium
> ```

So it will not be available on Professional.

Comment: Should you be interested in a cheaper option, you may wish to consider [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/). I haven't personally used it, but I know others who have and speak highly of it.

Comment: thank you. Is guess there is no free plugin/addon, is it? :-)

Comment: Not to my knowledge, unfortunately, though I admit I have not looked very far. If you find one, send it my way!

Answer (score 2):

Code coverage is available in premium and ultimate flavors of Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

A free alternative is the OpenCover: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCover

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work on VS2012, but if you happen to be using a more recent version https://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com/ has a VS plugin.